# Catch response from service to component?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new on angular/ionic. I'm trying to fetch a response from my API call.

Inside my service i have the following function:

```
setClockIn() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'bearer'
      })
    };
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in', httpOptions)
    .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data['data']);
    });
  }
```

And in my component i have the following function

```
ClockIn() {
    this.clockService.setClockIn();
    this.presentAlert(data);
  }
```

The response from `console.log(data['data']);` is my message from the API:

> "Clock updated"

Altough how can i fetch this data inside the same ClockIn function in order to send it as parameter to `this.presentAlert(data);` ?

I must use `.subscribe()` or `.pipe().map()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP GET request of angular's HttpClient returns an [observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable), so basically you should return the observable from the `setClockIn()` method and subscribe to it in the `ClockIn()` method of your component

```
setClockIn() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'bearer'
      })
    };

    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in', httpOptions);
}


ClockIn() {
    this.clockService.setClockIn().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['data']);
        this.presentAlert(data);
    });  
}
```

Comment: You are totally right, that is just was i looking for, thanks: